# Update form fields without refresh (prevent duplicated form)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to update (submit) form without refresh. I know it should be done using Ajax, so I found many examples on this website, but none of them was useful in my case. Here's the catch - I don't need to display any "success" or similar messages when form was submitted, I need to display exactly the same form, but with new values.

Examining examples on this site, I got it working, but when form is submitted via ajax (this part works fine), I see two forms displayed. Here's the example - http://www.lipskas.com/form/ (the whole source is available to view)

What should I change here?

P.S. If I change "$('#msg').html(html);" to "$('#myForm').html(html);" duplicated form doesn't appear, except one "little" problem - the form can be submitted only for the 1st time. Then no more values are properly submitted.

In case you are interested why I need to display exactly the same form (but with updated fields) again, it's because I built some type of calculator which has many fields, and when user updates ANY field, re-calculations are made ( http://lipskas.com/bandymas/ )

Comment: The question of HOW to do it has been answered multiple times and there are really good tutorials on the web. If you have a question on how to process the server response in javasript, you should  edit your question.

Comment: May be returning updated values in `JSON` object and then updating form fields by iterating `JSON` would be more appropriate. **OR** it might not be working when updating #myForm because ajax returning complete HTML i.e. script inclusion with HTML tag. Try returning only required form.

Comment: alpipego, can you please copy/paste a link on how to do it? I found many examples, but all of them were forms that submit data to other page (not the page itself)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "onclick" in the submit button and add this in the header above the chk function

```
<body>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="submitted - "><br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="submitted - "><br/>
    <select name="some_array[1]"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
    <select name="some_stuff[2]"><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_ok" value="test me">
</form>
</body>

function chk(this)
{
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"index.php",
    data: this.serialize(),
    cache:false,
    success: function (html){
        $('body').html(html);
        }
});
}
$(function(){
$("body").on("submit","#myForm",function(){
chk($(this));
return false;
 });
 });
```

Comment: The results is the same - two forms, or one form which only works for the 1st time.

P.S. Clewaned browser cache, seems something is different now. Going to check it on the main calculator.

Comment: Update - the form still doesn't work as expected. Now the page reloads on form submission, and it doesn't seem to posting data (URL becomes like "http://127.0.0.1/form/index.php?username=jonas&password=&some_array[1]=1&some_stuff[2]=3&submit_ok=test+me" after submitting form)

Comment: Form was updated on site (it now uses your code). Unfortunately, it doesn't even post data now